# Which Ros version is the most complete? Indigo or Jade or Kinetics?

Tags: ros, ros-jade, ros-indigo, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install Ros for the first time. but I've heard that indigo is most complete and for example kinetics doesn't have all the packages or isn't compatible with all of them.
So which version is the most complete to install?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255042/which-ros-version-is-the-most-complete?-indigo-or-jade-or-kinetics?/) by [aminya](https://answers.ros.org/users/29404/aminya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aminya](https://answers.ros.org/users/29404/aminya/) on 2017-02-22**:
Nobody? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will suggest [**indigo**](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo)

---

Originally posted by [matteopantano](https://answers.ros.org/users/29039/matteopantano/) with karma: 32 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1